# differentiation not making sense

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

good day,
I have been asked to differentiate the following:

$x^{395} * (1-2x)^{605}$

I have applied chain rule to $(1-2x)^{605}$ which gives me $-1210(1 - 2x)^{604}$ and the I apply product rule to the original function. the answer I get is:

$395(1−2x)^{605} * x^{394} − 1210(1−2x)^{604} * x^{395}$

but this is not the correct answer as I have been given it. it is:

$x^{394}*(1 − 2x)^{604} * (395 − 2000x)$ and I have no idea why?

any suggestions as i know that my differentiation is correct?

Comment: Find common factors; $a\cdot b-a\cdot c=a\cdot (b-c)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

applying the product and the chain rule we get
$$395x^{394}(1-2x)^{605}+x^{395}(1-2x)^{604}\cdot 605\cdot (-2)$$
this can be simplified
the result should be $$-5\,{x}^{394} \left( -1+2\,x \right) ^{604} \left( -79+400\,x \right) $$
or
$$x^{394}(-1+2x)^{604}(395-2000x)$$

Comment: I have to show that the actual answer is:
$x^{394}*(1 − 2x)^{604} * (395 − 2000x)*C$ which apparently is the correct answer. i can get to your answer Dr. but this seems not to be the case? has it have something to do with the fact that C is constant not dependent on x?

Comment: i have added a line, is this the searched result?

Comment: yeah, this result have i added!!!